# IIFE does not immediately invoke

Tags: javascript, iife

In the snippet below, the IIFE init() does not invoke.  I can post any other code if needed.

This is for a drop down menu.  I'm testing out `$Frame.Support()` so I'm pretty sure this has something to do with it, or more so the way I changed the code structure so that it is now an argument in a method.

```
$Frame.Support({
    name: 'Menu',
    body: function () {
        var top_element = $A("#hold_name")[0],
            bottom_element = $A("#wrap_bottom")[0],
            time_out_id = 0,
            TIME_DELAY = 1000;

        function top_mouse_over() {
            window.clearTimeout(time_out_id);
            bottom_element.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        function bottom_mouse_over() {
            window.clearTimeout(time_out_id);
        }
        function mouse_out() {
            time_out_id = window.setTimeout(function () {
                bottom_element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }, TIME_DELAY);
        }

        (function init() {
            alert('I can\'t see me.');
            top_element.addEventListener("mouseover", top_mouse_over, false);
            top_element.addEventListener("mouseout", mouse_out, false);
            bottom_element.addEventListener("mouseover", bottom_mouse_over, false);
            bottom_element.addEventListener("mouseout", mouse_out, false);
        }());
    }
});
```

Comment: Does something call the `body()` function? If not, then your code won't be run; it's inside that function.

Comment: I know that the code won't run if nothing calls it...but I thought Immediately Invoked Function Expressions run when the interpreter passes over...that's why I put it in an IIFE.

Comment: They are invoked when actually executed, just like any other function invocation. "Immediately" refers to the fact that the function is invoked immediately after being defined, which also happens at execution time.

Comment: `$Frame.Support()` is inside another IIFE...sot it is in the path of execution.

Comment: No, it's just code - that is, it's just a statement in your function. It runs only when the function is called. If it's *outside* a function, a the "global" level of a `<script>` block, then it will run when the browser evaluates the code.  Not if it's inside some function, however, unless the evaluation of the `<script>` block involves the calling of that function.